# Python - Define class with one method and one attribute

Tags: python, reflection, sys

I'm new to Python and trying create a program that defines a class called person that has one method called hello, and one attribute called name, which represents the name of the person. The hello method should print the following string to the screen:

‘My name is *name attribute* and I am a *name of class*’

1)Instantiate an object of the class,
2)Run the hello method of the instantiated object
(e.g., John.hello()),
3) Use sys.argv

Here is my code:

```
import sys

class person():
    def __init__(self,_name):
        self.name=_name
        _name = sys.argv[1]
    def hello(self):
        print (f"My name is {sys.argv[1]} I am a {self.__class__.__name__}")

p1 = person()
p1.hello()

def main():
    p = person()
    print (type(p))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example expected output:

```
My name is Obi-Wan and I am a person
<class '__main__.person'>
```

Actual output:

```
  File "classname.py", line 10, in <module>
    p1 = person()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: '_name'
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help!

Comment: You need to pass the `name` in `person()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue was that you've created a class which expects an argument, but then did not give it the requested argument.
Since the `__init__` function requires the `_name` argument, the initialization of the `person` class must be done with a name, for example `person('my_name')`.

Since you get the name as an input, you probably want to save it in the class and reuse it, instead of extracting it from `sys.argv` every time. So the end result should look something like this-

```
import sys


class person():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def hello(self):
        print(f"My name is {self.name} I am a {self.__class__.__name__}")


def main():
    input_name = sys.argv[1]
    p = person(input_name)
    p.hello()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If this works for you (which it should), mark this as the correct solution.

Comment: This works to print the string but it's missing the name of the class which was suppose to come after the string <class ‘__main__.person’> in the expected output. How do I do that? I though the if __name__ == "__main__" is suppose to do this.

Comment: Then you can change `{self.__class__.__name__}` to be `{self.__class__}` @MCly

Comment: I did that and it comes out 'My name is Obi-Wan and I am a <class '__main__.person'>' instead of 'My name is Obi-Wan and I am a person'
                 '<class '__main__.person'>'

Comment: I added 'print (self.__class___)' under the 'print(f"My name is {self.name} and I am a {self.__class__.__name__}")' and it worked! Thank you so much @Guy!